# Redirecting to a desired query string after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

an upload form, inputted data of which shall not be stored in the database are submitted on a dynamically launched page which query string is as following:

```
www.site.com/test?id=1
```

the form's action is as following:

```
<form id="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and header location is as following:

```
 header('Location: '. basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). '?file=xyz');
```

how should i modify the header and/or form's action so that it is redirected to

```
www.site.com/test?file=xyz&id=1
```

or

```
www.site.com/test?id=1&file=xyz
```

after submit?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the ID into a hidden field:

```
<form id="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
  ...
</form>
```

Then it can pass the ID along in the redirect:

```
header('Location: ' basename($_Server['PHP_SELF']). '?file=xyz&id=' . $_POST['id']);
```

Comment: hi Barmar, your code `header('Location: ' .basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']). '?file=xyz&id=' . $_REQUEST['id']);`

is very close to serve the purpose but it can't retrieve the value of `id` from the query string. it only returns `www.site.com/test?file=xyz&id=`. i even tried that replacing `REQUEST` with `GET`. something might be missing here. any idea? thanks,

Comment: See the updated answer, I don't think I understood the sequence of events earlier.

Comment: that did it @Barmar. i have learnt something new. thanks & regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
header ('Location: ' . basename ($_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']) . '?file=xyz&id=1');
```

Comment: hi @Mikhail Vladimirov, thanks for your suggestion. may be it was my fault as i was unable to explain my question more clearly. although your answer looks correct the code won't be applicable here as id value in the query string shall be launched dynamically.